# Time series with 1 minute frequency in R using the ts() function

Tags: r, time-series

I have 18,596 temperature data at 1 minute interval, from 2017-05-31T17:02:30.000Z to 2017-06-13T14:57:30.000Z. I want to use the ts() function to create a time series object with frequency of every 1 minute. I have tried the following but it obviously doesn't work:

```
ts(data, start=c(2017,5,31,17,2,30), end=c(2017,6,13,14,57,30))
```

How should I write it?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the following:

```
# find out how many minutes are in this period
(as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2017-06-13 14:57:30")) -
  as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2017-05-31 17:02:30"))) / 60
# 18595

# create a time series object (random data as example)
tsdat <- ts(data = rnorm(18595), 
  start = as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2017-05-31 17:02:30")),
  end = as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2017-06-13 14:57:30")), 
  frequency = 60)
```

or, even better, use extended time series objects from package **zoo** or **xts**:

```
library("zoo")
tsdat <- zoo(rnorm(18596), 
  order.by = seq(as.POSIXct("2017-05-31 17:02:30"), length=18596, by="min"))
head(tsdat)


library("xts")
tsdat <- xts(rnorm(18596), 
  order.by = seq(as.POSIXct("2017-05-31 17:02:30"), length=18596, by="min"))
head(tsdat)
```

More about this can be found [here](https://rpubs.com/mpfoley73/504487).